# Count how many projects are in the projects table

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to count how many projects I have in the projects table. My code currently gets the count of project with the specific id.

I simply want to count over *all* projects that exist in my table.

controller code:

```
public function countProjects()
{
    $count = Projects::where('id','0')->count();
    return view('projects.test')->with('count', $count);
}
```

Comment: num_of_rows() could work..

Comment: Delete the `where` statement? `Projects::count();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just remove the where.

```
$count = Projects::count();
```

The `where()` builder method returns `$this` after attaching the criteria, in order to allow method chaining. So if you eliminate it, you will still be calling `count()` on the model.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in laravel site

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries

```
$users = DB::table('users')->count();
```

Similarly you can use as follows

```
public function countProjects()
{
    $count = DB::table('Projects')->where('id','0')->count();
    return view('projects.test')->with('count', $count);
}
```

Other option is 
As given in this link 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

```
$count = App\Flight::where('active', 1)->count();
```

Which match with your code.
I suggest
Just print $count in controller and check what exactly data is there in the variable and then accordingly make changes in code.

I think this will help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Projects::get()->count()`